# prove a theorem in agda. Error : should be a function type, but isn't

Tags: agda

Here is the theorem that I want to prove.

```
prob4 : ∀(w x y z : ℕ) → w * (x + y + z) ≡ z * w + x * w + w * y
prob 4 = {!!}
```

This is what I wrote

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Properties.Simple
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

prob4a : ∀ (w x y z : ℕ) → w * (x + y + z) ≡ w * x + w * y + w * z
prob4a 0 x y z = refl
prob4a (suc w) x y z rewrite prob4a w x y z
            | +-assoc (x + y + z) (w * x) (w * y) (w * z) = ?
```

I created a new theorem prob4a in order to arrange the output in a correct order. And it's able to use theorems in nat.thms.agda to prove it.

and the error is

> `x + y + z + w * x + w * y ≡ x + y + z + (w * x + w * y)` should be a
>   function type, but it isn't
>   when checking that `(w * z)` is a valid argument to a function of
>   type `x + y + z + w * x + w * y ≡ x + y + z + (w * x + w * y)`

so what 's that mean? and how can i correct it in order to let the prove work?

Comment: In general it's better to copy / paste code & error messages rather than using screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

[`+-assoc`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.Properties.Simple.html#580) only takes 3 arguments but you've passed 4 arguments to it.

Agda complains than an equality type is not a function type because the result of `+-assoc` applied to 3 arguments is an equality type but passing a 4th argument means you want it to be a function.